# How to show number keyboard for a text input field in mobile application

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, cordova

I am using `Cordova` + `react js` to build an Android app and I have a requirement to render a currency number on a input field. When this `input field` get focus, it shows a number keyboard.

After users type in some numbers, it will format the number as a text string. For example, if users type `394,333.2930`, it will render it as `$394,333.293`. There is no problem for me to format the string. The problem is how can I show a number keyboard for a `text` input field.

I know it works for a input with `number` type but it doesn't allow users type `,` or currency sign. Also with number input field, users can type multiple dot `.` which I don't want this happen. So how can I show a number only keyboard for a text input field in `Cordova` application? I am not sure whether this is a `Cordova` specific problem or a general web application problem.

I have tried to use `tel` but it still shows the characters as below screen shot. They are shown as a gray characters after each number. How can I get rid of them?

```
<input id="numberInput" type="tel" maxlength="6"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple ways but I also had exact same situation and I am doing like below. Use `type="tel"` and add check on `keydown` event to handle unwanted chars like `"#", "+", "*", ";", ",", "-"`. Below is code:

HTML:

```
<input id="numberInput" type="tel" maxlength="6"/>
```

JS:

```
// validation for targetSalary input
var invalidChars = ["#", "+", "*", ";", ",", "-"];
numberInput.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (invalidChars.includes(event.key)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Hope this will help you!

**Update:**

As you have changed the requirement and as per this new requirement you want to **hide special chars from keyboard**
Answer to this requirement is that you **can not hide special chars from keyboard** in normal way. **Maybe** you can achieve it by creating your own custom keyboard.

Comment: I have applied your solution but it still shows the characters on the keyboard.

Comment: @ZhaoYi yes chars are shown but user will not be able to enter them. Do you want hide those chars? **You can not hide them**. If you want make your own custom keyboard.